# how to customize an artisan command in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i want to customize artisan command for maintenance mode and add new argument to this command, how can i do this?
like this: php artisan down --secret=maintenanceSecret --time=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to copy that command (vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/DownCommand.php) and make a new one with your logic.... that way you will always have it and know that it works.

```
php artisan make:command YourCommandName
```